# How do I search a list that is in a nested list (list of list) without loop in Python?

Tags: python, list

I am perfectly aware of that..

```
sample=[[1,[1,0]],[1,1]]
[1,[1,0]] in sample
```

This will return True.

But what I want to do here is this.

```
sample=[[1,[1,0]],[1,1]]
[1,0] in sample
```

I want the return to be True, but this returns False.
I can do this:

```
sample=[[1,[1,0]],[1,1]]
for i in range(len(sample)):
    [1,0] in sample[i]
```

But I am wondering if there is any *better* or *efficient* way of doing it.

Comment: You can use `for index, elem in enumerate(sample): [1, 0] in elem` over `range(len())` --unrelated, just cleaner

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can use chain from itertools to merge the lists and then search in the returned list.

```
>>> sample=[[1,[1,0]],[1,1]]
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> print [1,0]  in chain(*sample)
True
```

Comment: This would fail however if any element of the initial list is not iterable.

Comment: the question says list of lists. if you want to find lists in an arbitrary structure this would be entering parsing territory. where pattern matching or visitors would perhaps apply. (note that both would require traversal of a set of known structures).

Answer (score 4):

A recursive solution that would work for arbitrary (max recursion depth aside) deep nesting. Also works if any elements of the outermost list are not iterables themselves.

```
from functools import partial

def contains_nested(some_iterable, elmnt):
    try:
        if elmnt in some_iterable:
            return True
    except TypeError:  # some_iterable is not iterable
        return False
    else:
        return any(map(partial(contains_nested, elmnt=elmnt), some_iterable))
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to solve this completely without a loop. But in Python you should never write `for i in range(len(sample))`.

So the answer to your question: Yes there is a better and faster way you could loop your list `for i in sample`

The way Python handles the loops is really fast and works also very well with a lot of entriey (more than 50.000).

Answer (score 1):

You can [flatten](https://stackoverflow.com/a/952952/5276734) your `sample` list and then search in that flattened list:

```
> sample = [[1, [1, 0]], [1, 1]]
> [1, 0] in [item for sublist in sample for item in sublist]
> True
```

Comment: But then `[1,1]` will fail since it'll be flatten to `1,1`.

Comment: @MarounMaroun yes, it will not find the `1,1` but the "working" for loop given in the question will not find this either, so I thought it should be this way.

Comment: Flatten the list may not able to handle all issues